# Angular test mat menu triggered click and count items

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test mat menu items length, but it seems there aren't any items at all (buttons length is 0) after click. Maybe the problem is in the click itself

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MatComponent);
const trigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-menu-trigger'));
trigger.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-menu-item');
expect(buttons.length).toEqual(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The beforeEach needs to be as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```